# How to calculate the number of years and the answer is a range of age?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where someone places their year of birth. I need to get the age range of the person.

Example: For someone born in 1979 the range would be 40-45.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide some of your code? It's hard to debug without your code. By providing some code, you'll get more views which will result in a faster answer.

Comment: Try (copy and paste) something like this https://playcode.io/350172?tabs=script.js,preview,console

Answer (score 2):

This answer depends on where you want to do this task.

Do you want to show it to the user before or after submitting the form?
Do you want to save it on the backend into a database?

Either way, here's something you can try:

1. Get the current year

   - I recommend w3school for things like these: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp
2. Get the difference between the year the user entered and the current year.

   - Don't forget error handling
3. Check the range and display the result

   - Use a conditional statement (if/else or switch).

This answer is very general because I'm not sure how you would like to implement the method. Hope this provides some hints!

Comment: Welcome to SO! While the question is vague, usually it's important to have some code in your answer instead of linking to another site. This helps create a more robust answer.

Comment: thank you, sorry, i don´t speak english; but i format again my question.